# Android Rating bar Invisible

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, ratingbar

Below is my code for the rating bar

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBarU"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:progressTint="#FBE140"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

The problem I encounter is that , when I set the style to,

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

The rating bar gets invisible
[image: image1]

and when I try

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
```

[image]

The rating bar shows all 10 stars but they are un-clickable when run on my emulator.
All I want is for my rating bar to show all 10 stars and fit to the screen size
Please help ! Im very new to android development

Answer (score 0):

Think are you using inside the **LinearLayout(Horizontal)**. Can you please use this code in vertical linearlayout

```
        <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBarU"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:progressTint="#FBE140"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `layout_height` **wrap_content** don't use a specific dp value, also I didn't understand why you have used `layout_weight` as you are setting a specific height of `45dp`(it should be wrap_content) and setting width as wrap_content. Your rating bar should be look like this

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarU"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="10"
    android:progressTint="#FBE140"
    android:stepSize="1" />
```

Output

[image]